# outlook 2007 not displaying image button in email

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am creating an html email which uses image buttons as

```
<input type="image" src="images/right_nav1.bmp" width="200" height="37" name="right_nav1" style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0; display:block;" />
                    <input type="image" src="images/right_nav2.bmp" width="200" height="37" name="right_nav2" style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0; display:block;" />
                    <input type="image" src="images/right_nav3.bmp" width="200" height="37" name="right_nav3" style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0; display:block;" />              
                    <input type="image" src="images/right_nav4.bmp" width="200" height="37" name="right_nav4" style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0; display:block;" />
```

The images are not getting displayed. Is there a work around for displaying image buttons?

Comment: Where is `images/` supposed to be pointing to in the context of an E-Mail?

Comment: I am storing the images in an online server address http://www.domain.com/images/right_nav.bmp

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- you need to use absolute paths. The E-Mail has no connection to your web site and its paths. `<img src="http://.....">`
- Don't use BMP images, support is going to be spotty. Use JPG, GIF or PNG images instead.

Comment: I have used absolute paths as well as PNG images. It still does not show up. It shows up only when i use an image and not <input type="image">

Comment: @user I'm sorry, I *completely* overlooked that you're using `input` elements. Why are you using those in the first place? Do you have a form in your E-Mail? They tend to encounter very tight restrictions in most E-Mail clients so it *might* be simply impossible to use them.

Comment: @user check out http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/entry/674/using-forms-in-email/